# TCPDF inline vs save-to-file image quality

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am generating PDFs with TCPDF.  I have a test script that generates an inline pdf, as well as a script that saves a PDF to the server and then emails it out.

The PDFs that are saved to file have extremely poor image quality on some images.  You can see this below:

[image: Poor image]

The PDFs shown inline (in the browser) have perfect image quality:
[image: Good image]

Does anyone know why there would be a difference between the two?  Same code, just saved differently as per the documentation:

`$pdf->Output(self::$base_url.$filename, 'I');`

vs

`$pdf->Output(self::$base_url.$filename, 'F');`

Comment: Are you using the same PDF viewer (Adobe x Firefox reader?)

Comment: I am using Adobe when viewing a physical file, and whatever Chrome uses to display inline PDFs.

Would there be a major difference like this between the two?  I always thought PDFs were to be extremely similar between systems.

Comment: They might be extremelly similar, but still different with different bugs. Try to download the version shown in Chrome and have a look in Adobe.

Comment: The document is the exact same.  One version is shown inline (Chrome's PDF viewer) and the other is saved to disc.

So it's the same thing.  I use the inline version just to test layout changes without having to physically open the file.

I viewed the inline version on both Chrome, FF, and Safari without issue.  Just the file-based version that is a failure :/

Please let me know if I misunderstood your suggestion :)

Comment: It sounds ok. You might check the `$jpeg_quality` variable if it changes somehow (for JPG images).

Comment: I have set `$pdf->SetJPEGQuality(100);` without any success.  I also tried to use the suggested `$pdf->setImageScale(1.53);` as seen in other posts on SO, but to no avail.  I have reverted back to using `$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);`.

Comment: Are the filesizes simular when compared ? Is there any compression taking place here ? It should be false by default, also any errors/warnings in the php logs ?

Comment: You said this problem is for "some images", so I guess for others images works fine. Look for differences between images that works and imagen that doesn't. Maybe something obvious (for example, jpg vs. png) or something more difficult to see (for example, baseline jpg vs. progressive jpg).

However, please also try @Jakuje requirement: when viewing inline version, save it to your hard disc and then open it with Adobe.

Comment: @Gurnzbot , which type of image you are using ? (JPEG, PNG, BMP)

Comment: reffer this link : https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/404343d4/  (if not visited still then).

Comment: Try to use 'FI' option - it duplicates the same content to file and browser, and then compare results. I suspect, it is your PDF file viewer that spoils  images

Comment: I had a similar issue with PNGs using alpha transparency, are you using PNG or JPG? maybe just start your PDF by adding a full dimension rectangle with white background

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the image supplied to me was sent as a .jpg, however the image was actually a .png.  I guess TCPDF got confused and hence distorted the image.

I re-saved the image for web as .jpg using Photoshop and all is well.

Soooo.... the client is to blame ;)
(For reals, because I was told to use the exact image given).

Answer (score -1):

Use "I" to open PDF in a browser, and "F" for save it as a file.

Comment: Clearly I've done this, as stated very clearly in my code examples.